# Microsoft Excel Referencing data

Tags: excel, reference, lookup, cells, transpose

I am trying to figure out how to look up a cell to see if it contains a name from a list I have specified, we will use "Hofmann Trucking" for example.

Using columns a,b and c where column a contains average hours it takes for truck to travel from point a to point b, column b contains the carrier information (Hofmann Trucking) and finally column c which is where I would like the answer to go.

I want column c to return the time listed in column a, only if Hofmann trucking is the carrier in column b. If another carrier is listed I would like to put that information in column d.

In the end these times will be averaged per carrier per day so I can easily show how much time is spent traveling to and from certain areas by different companies.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Col A       Col B                Col C                             Col D
8           Hoffman Trucking     =If(B1="Hoffman Trucking",A1,0)   =A1-C1
```

Put those 2 formulas in columns C & D and drag down...

Comment: Assuming multiple possible values in Col B, he'll need to reference a list, e.g., on Sheet1, cells A1:A10.  In that case, Col C formula should be like `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,FALSE))),0,A1)`

Comment: @DavidZemens Ok, so are you saying if I had a list of carriers in sheet 1 column a, and used sheet two as the calculation sheet?

Comment: @user2208691 `Sheet1` could reference *any* worksheet (just change the name). Likewise `$A$1:$A$10` you could change to refer to any range where you keep the list.  This: `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10` indicates that the list is in a worksheet called "Sheet1" and in cells A1:A10. Modify as needed.

Comment: Updated, I think I had the last two arguments flipped. I think you need this instead which will return the value from A1 if the result of the Match function is not an error, otherwise, it will return 0. `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,FALSE))),A1,0)`

Comment: Great! You should give credit to @John Bustos for this answer though, I just modified it slightly to account for variance in column B.